# Iterate over array with max value limit and return

Tags: javascript, arrays

How does one return an array with a max value set, in this case, where they're greater than 5?

```
arr.forEach(function(index, theArray) {
   if (theArray[index] > 5) theArray[index] = 5
})
console.log(arr) // [5.5, 0.1 8.4, 4.3, etc]
```

Would like `[5, 0.1, 5, 4.3, etc]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` and `Math.min`:

```
arr = arr.map(n => Math.min(n, 5));
```

Comment: For large inputs, does `map` end up creating a second mapped copy of the elements vs. in place modification.  Or are compilers smart enough to see that you're overwriting `arr` immediately?

Comment: @arcyqwerty Not sure what implementations do, but yes, it may waste memory for huge arrays. But in that case I would use typedarrays instead of normal arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an argument to eat the current element from the `forEach` function.

**Input**

```
var arr = [5.5, 0.1, 8.4, 4.3];
```

**Code**

```
arr.forEach(function(_, index, theArray) {
   if (theArray[index] > 5) theArray[index] = 5;
})
console.log(arr)
```

**Output**

> [5, 0.1, 5, 4.3]

Referring to the documentation:

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **callback**
>
>   Function to execute for each element, taking three arguments:
>
>   - **currentValue**
>
>     The current element being processed in the array.
>   - **index**
>
>     The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>   - **array**
>
>     The array that forEach() is being applied to.
> - **thisArg**
>
>   Optional. Value to use as this when executing callback.
>
> **Return value**
>
> ```
> undefined
> ```

Your code can also be shortened a bit, taking advantage of this otherwise unused variable.

```
arr.forEach(function(element, index, theArray) {
  if (element > 5) theArray[index] = 5;
}
```

---

Note that if you want to do this without mutating the original array, you also have the option of map.

```
arr.map(function(e) { return Math.max(e, 5); }
```